# Mac, Jupyter, import packages

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter

when I try to import the train_test_split function, I always get the warning"

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DistanceMetric32'
```

my scikit learn is 1.2.0

I want to use the train_test_split function.

Comment: This is not a warning, this is an error. Please include your code and the whole traceback.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually this an Error, not a Warning !!!**

**Try with Reinstalling scikit-learn to version 1.1.0 or 1.0.0**